# How to keep unstructured file name as value and insert into database

Tags: datastage, ibm-infosphere

I'm new in using IBM Data Stage, i need to keep the file name that i set in the unstructured file in filepath as a value. Then i need to insert that value in `original_file` column of my table for all rows automatically. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the file name is a job parameter and will be provided each job run you could use a Transformer - add a new column "original_file" and use the parameter name as derivation.

Note: A parameter is provided i.e. file_name will be referenced in DataStage with #file_name# (i.e. in the file stage) but will be referenced in the Transformer as file_name (without the #s)

Comment: I am not sure if I understand the problem you are describing. original_file is the column name and the content should be whatever you provided as file_name when you start the job (for the job parameter)